# Get the values from a string

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I need help with a quick question I a string "07/10/2014" how can I get first the year "2014",second the month "10" ,third the day- "07" with out "/" only the values in VB.NET

Please show me the full way how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at this.

```
Dim MyDate As Date
MyDate = "07/10/2014"
MsgBox(Format(MyDate, "dd")) ' dd gives you day number
MsgBox(Format(MyDate, "MM")) ' MM gives you month number
MsgBox(Format(MyDate, "YYYY")) ' YYYY gives you year number
```

The full list of date fomatting string could be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1) (MSDN)

**UPDATE**

Use following example to assign to a string variable

```
Dim DayOfString As String DayOfString
DayOfString = Format(MyDate, "dd")
```

Comment: It coming has a string, how can I get it as a string also?

Comment: Assign these values to a string variable instead of MsgBox. See my updated answer

Comment: See more example here to see how VB.Net's Format function works http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-AU/library/59bz1f0h%28v=vs.90%29.aspx

Answer (score 2):

First declare it like this `Dim x as Date = "07/10/2014"`. And to get the individual values use `x.Day`, `x.Month` and `x.Year`

Answer (score 2):

Use the DateTime.Parse() method then use the return DateTime structure to extract the Month, Day, Year properties (similar to DJK's answer above).

If the thread's current culture is set to one that understands "mm/dd/yyyy" format, then the code can be as simple as:

```
    Dim dt As DateTime = DateTime.Parse("07/15/2014")
    MessageBox.Show(String.Format("Month: {0}; Day: {1}; Year: {2}", dt.Month, dt.Day, dt.Year))
```

Comment: dates can also be created using a literal: `Dim dt As DateTime = #07/15/2015#`